# Evaluating triple integral over a region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the triple integral over the indicated region

$\int\int\int_R ydV$

over that part of the cube $0\le x,y,z \le1$ lying above the plane $y+z=1$ and below the plane $x+y+z=2$

How do I chose the order of integration and how do I set up the integration limits ? Do I just solve both equations for z or something like that?

What exactly is the consistent pattern / method  in setting up these integration limits for triple integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane $y+z=1$ can also be written $z=1-y $ so above that plane means $z>1-y $. In the same way "below the plane $x+y+z=2$ means $z <2-x-y $. Thus $1-y < z < 2-x-y $.

The limits for $x $ and $y $ are just $0$ and $1$.

Comment: ok so it would just be: $\int_0^1 \int_0^1\int_{1-y}^{2-x-y}ydzdydx$ ? the answer on this problem should be 5/24, but I got 1/2 calculating that.

Comment: I missed that we should have $z <1$. You can split the integral into two parts; one for which $2-x-y<1$ and we use $2-x-y $ as upper bound for $z $, and one for which $2-x-y>1$ and we use $1$ as upper bound for $z $.

Comment: What do you mean by splitting up the integral in two parts? how should the integral be set up? it's a bit confusing here, don't I have 4 values for which z can range between? 0, 1, 1-y, 2-x-y?

Comment: When $x+y <1$ then $2-x-y>1$ so the upper bound for $z $ should be $1$. When $x+y>1$ then the upper bound for $z $ should be $2-x-y $. Therefore we can split the integral into one where $1-y <z <1$ and one where $1-y <z <2-x-y $.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 dx \int_0^{1-x} dy \int_{1-y}^1 dz \, y + \\ \int_0^1 dx \int_{1-x}^1 dy \int_{1-y}^{2-x-y} dz \, y $$

Comment: why does the integral go from 0 to 1-x?

Comment: We have two cases: when $x+y <1$ the upper bound for $z $ is $1$, and when $x+y >1$ the upper bound for $z $ is $2-x-y $. I have therefore split the integral into two parts; one for each case. The first triple integral has $0 <y <1-x $ and $1$ as upper bound for $z $, and the second triple integral has $1-x <y <1$ and $2-x-y $ as upper bound for $z $.

Comment: ok I think I understand, just curious, how would it be if you had y+z=1/2 instead of y+z=1? (with everything else staying the same). Then I'd get 1/2-y<z<2-x-y, but how would I set up the integral in this case? knowing that 0<z<1 as well

Comment: Why isn't is possible to solve both equations for z and set them equal to each other in this problem? Isn't that the general way in solving  problems like this when there is two surfaces bounding R?

Comment: Then you would have to make another split at $y=1/2$ and there would be two splits in $y $, one at $1/2$ and one at $1-x $. But there would also be two cases for the ordering of these breakpoints: $1/2 < 1-x $ and $1/2> 1-x $. Therfore also a split in $x $ is required: $0 <x <1/2$ and $1/2 <x <1$. There will thus be six cases, each resulting in one triple integral.

Comment: What equations for $z $ do you refer to?

Comment: I am refering to the equations: z=2-x-y and z=1-y

Comment: Solving $2-x-y = 1-y $ gives $x=1$ which is at the boundary of the cube. Thus it doesn't give anything useful.